# Magento2 - How to get current website id in Frontend?

Tags: magento2, multi-website

How to get current customer `website id` in Magento2.3 frontend, to precise in `customer_register_success` observer.

Comment: Refer this link https://jutesenthil-wordpress-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2016/05/18/get-current-website-id-in-magento2/amp/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D#aoh=15840685659567&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fjutesenthil.wordpress.com%2F2016%2F05%2F18%2Fget-current-website-id-in-magento2%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already declared the observer class in events.xml

```
namespace Bp\StackOverflow\Observer\Frontend\Customer;

class RegisterSuccess implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
){
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}


public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {
    //Your Website Id
    $currentWebsiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
}
}
```

Comment: Is this the right way to get a website Id in Observer? Code:   https://justpaste.it/732i5

Comment: Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId(); this will return the website id for current store.
and this is for magento 1.

Comment: For magento 2 how to get a website id?

Comment: you can see the answer above. this is the correct way to get website id. let me know where you are facing the problem.

Comment: Is my website filter condition right? https://paste.ofcode.org/wiDMNmBj7DAmXjUkiT8YmJ

Comment: Error : Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Gta\EnablePaymentMethod\Observer\PaymentMethodEnable::$_storeManager in /var/www/html/test/app/code/Gta/EnablePaymentMethod/Observer/PaymentMethodEnable.php on line 15

Comment: Updated Code for you. https://justpaste.it/74d31 . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Test\Custom\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Custom extends AbstractHelper {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getStore() {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    }

    public function getWebsiteId() {
        return $this->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    }   
}

.phtml  File Get Website Id

$helper = $this->helper('Test\Custom\Helper\Custom');

echo $current_web_id =  $helper->getWebsiteId();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Test\Test\Observer\Customer;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Success implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface 
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $WebsiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    }
}
```